# How to properly set TinyMCE emoticons to Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce-rails

I installed gem tinymce-rails. It's works. But when I added `emoticons` plugin, they are **black and white**. **Why it is unattractive? What did I do wrong?**

application.js:

```js
...
//= require tinymce-jquery
...
```

It is tinymce.yml:

```
toolbar:
  - styleselect | bold italic | undo redo
  - image | link | emoticons
plugins:
  - image
  - link
  - emoticons
```

form slim:

```rb
.post-form
  = form_with model: resource, method: :post, url: posts_path do |f|
    .field
      = f.text_area :body, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 120
      = tinymce_assets
      = tinymce
    .submit
      = f.submit 'Опубликовать'
```

It is the result:

[Image of my emoji](https://yadi.sk/i/ovc02KlT_mo-Nw)

Use ruby-on-rails Rails 5.2.2, tinymce-rails-5.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The link is not working. But I'm guessing what you are seeing is the font's images for the unicode character that represents the emoji, some browsers may replace the characters with actual images. Read here https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/emoticons/ `Note: it doesn’t automatically convert text emoticons into graphical smilies.`, that conversions depends on you.

Check this gem, I guess you can combine it with the tinymce string https://github.com/wpeterson/emoji